# XSLT 2.0 reverse key with multiple entries, from external document

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I've got this document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Mappings</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Code in</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Name</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Code out</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Mapping mode</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Change</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>OK</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Add</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Edit</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Add/Update</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
</file>
```

I've got a file with references to these UI controls:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- DICT_min.xml -->
<DICTIONARY>
    <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="ui58384" DICT_STRING="Reset target"/>
    <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="ui16245" DICT_STRING="Mappings"/>
    <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="ui56897" DICT_STRING="Mappings"/>
    <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="ui56841" DICT_STRING="Code in"/>
    <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="ui56850" DICT_STRING="Code in"/>
    <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="ui56868" DICT_STRING="Code in"/>
    <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="ui56869" DICT_STRING="Code out"/>
    <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="ui56919" DICT_STRING="Add/Update"/>
    <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="ui56920" DICT_STRING="Add/Update"/>
    <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="dml3152" DICT_STRING="Retrieved"/>
    <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="dml3261" DICT_STRING="Sent"/>
</DICTIONARY>
```

I'd like, ideally, to get them combined: so that the id attribute is in the original file. A bit tricky, as there are often multiple IDs for each possible string. But if I have multiple  elements, it will help the users, as it is easier for them to delete the misplaced elements, than type in the correct attributes. So I am aiming for this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content
        <uicontrol ref="ui16245">Mappings</uicontrol>
        <uicontrol ref="ui56897">Mappings</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content
        <uicontrol ref="ui56841">Code in</uicontrol>
        <uicontrol ref="ui56850">Code in</uicontrol>
        <uicontrol ref="ui56868">Code in</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Name</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol ref="ui56869">Code out</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Mapping mode</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Change</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>OK</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Add</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol>Edit</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content
        <uicontrol ref="ui56919">Add/Update</uicontrol>
        <uicontrol ref="ui56920">Add/Update</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
</file>
```

I've been trying a large number of xslt commands. In my naivety and folly, the latest idea I have had is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="dictstrings" select="document('DICT_min.xml')"/>
<xsl:key name="ui_ids" match="DICT_ENTRY" use="@DICT_STRING"/>

    <!--Identity template, copies all content -->
     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Template for uicontrol that provides custom behavior -->
    <xsl:template match="uicontrol">  
        <xsl:variable name="uistring" select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$dictstrings"> 
                <xsl:with-param name="uistring" select="$uistring"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DICT_ENTRY">
        <xsl:param name="uistring"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('ui_ids',$uistring)">
            <xsl:element name="uicontrol">
                <xsl:attribute name="ref">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@DICT_ID"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="@DICT_STRING"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you are knowledgeable and observant enough to see (I'm not), it produces this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<DICTIONARY/>More content</dummy_content>
    <dummy_content>Contextual content<DICTIONARY/>More content</dummy_content>
...
```

Do you know why my context has become messed up here, trying to access the external DICT_min.xml file? How do I control the context, so that the xsl and xpath knows which file to search in?

Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Note: "Mappings." does not match "Mappings".

Comment: hm, yes, sorry, a typo in transferring it onto the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<xsl:apply-templates select="$dictstrings">` use `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('ui_ids', ., $dictstrings)">`.

Then your template should be

```
<xsl:template match="DICT_ENTRY">
  <uicontrol ref="{@DICT_ID}">
   <xsl:value-of select="@DICT_STRING"/>
  </uicontrol>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: But very surreally, it has also added the xmlns attributes of the XSLT stylesheet to the uicontrol element too:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <file>
     <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ref="ui16245">Mappings</uicontrol><uicontrol xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ref="ui56897">Mappings</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content> ....

Comment: I found a workaround for that last surreal problem. I just deleted those two attributes from the XSLT header. Now it's perfect. How they got into the final XML output, I do not understand.

Comment: Except that the uicontrol elements that do not have a corresponding DICT_ENTRY, (there are some in the full version), do not appear in the output:  <dummy_content>Contextual contentMore content</dummy_content>
 <dummy_content>Contextual content<uicontrol ref="ui56869">Code out</uicontrol>More content</dummy_content>
 <dummy_content>Contextual contentMore content</dummy_content>

Comment: As for the prefixes, add `exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` element. As for preserving elements that don't have a reference, change the match pattern from `match="uicontrol"` to `match="uicontrol[key('ui_ids', ., $dictstrings)]"`, that way the identity transformation template should do the job for those elements you simply want to copy.

Comment: That's much better than what I just tried: [ <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="count(key('ui_ids', ., $dictstrings)) &gt; 0">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ui_ids', ., $dictstrings)"> 
     <xsl:with-param name="uistring" select="$uistring"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>  ]

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="dictstrings" select="document('DICT_min.xml')"/>
<xsl:key name="dict_entry" match="DICT_ENTRY" use="@DICT_STRING"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="uicontrol[key('dict_entry', ., $dictstrings)]">  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('dict_entry', ., $dictstrings)"/> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DICT_ENTRY">  
    <uicontrol ref="{@DICT_ID}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@DICT_STRING"/>
    </uicontrol>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```